# I need to match all a tags that contain imgs from a string

Tags: regex, image

I need to match all a tags that contain imgs from a string.

```
<a href="#1" title="##1"><img src="...." alt="####1" title="####1"/></a>
<a href="#2" title="##2"><img src="...." alt="####2" title="####2"/></a>
<a href="#3" title="##2"><img src="...." alt="####2" title="####3"/></a>
```

Thanks

Comment: Which lang are you running? Why don't you use a html parser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a\s*[^>]*>.*?<img\s*[^>]*>.*<\/a>
```

Try this.This should do it.